# A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1064 line 34

Tags: mariadb

Error Number: 1064

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near `WHERE`_id`IS NULL` at line 2

```
SELECT * WHERE `_id` IS NULL
```

Filename: views/backend/header.php

Line Number: 34

My code:

```
<?php $name = $this->db->get_where($this->session->userdata('login_type'), array($this->session->userdata('login_type').'_id' => $this->session->userdata('login_user_id')))->row()->name;
echo $name;
?>
```

Comment: Please show us the generated SQL.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the name of the table is not being set, please double check the value in `$this->session->userdata('login_type')`